# my website not working after GKE cluster version upgrade and node pool version upgrade

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I upgraded my GKE cluster and node pools to a newer version but now my website is not working. I am a developer with no knowledge of deployment to GKE. I updated the new external IP on godaddy and still facing the same issue. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you post some details about your deployment as well as your cluster?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.